# Draw directed graph with networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to build a quotes net, to identify the most quoted authors. I was using the read_pajek() function from NetworkX and visualizing it with Matplotlib.
It's great, looks like this:

example image (png)

[image]

But the thing is that I need the graph to be directed, because this way I cannot measure correctly the centrality in the graph.

Also, I want to be able to load a File.net and not to build the graph every time I execute the code.

I have searched in other questions, but they do not solve my problem.

Does anyone know any other way to do this?

Comment: How are you constructing your graph?

Comment: This is the code I am using to create the graph. The file Red_Citas.net contains the matrix with the vertices and edges.

import networkx as net
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

chart = net.read_pajek("Red_Citas.net")
net.draw(chart)
plot.show()

Comment: Ok so, you are actually loading a _pajec format_ file graph, not constructing the graph each time. The file loads into a `multigraph` networkx object or `dimultigraph` if the graph if directed. If you don't want a `dimultigraph` just a `digraph` just do `chart = net.Digraph(chart)`.

Comment: Done!! Thank you very much. Now it works, and it is directed. But it changed the way it is represented, now is a circle and not the way it showed before. I guess is a problem of the way it visualizes it.

Comment: what function are you using to draw it? are you using networkx.draw_networkx or directly matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can read of the [documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.pajek.read_pajek.html), `read_pajek` should automatically return a directed graph if the graph it is reading in is directed.  I've also looked at the source code, and it does have some tests for whether the graph is directed.

So if your graph isn't directed after you read it in, that suggeststhat the data file you're reading doesn't have the appropriate format to be interpreted as directed.  Otherwise, perhaps some later step in your code converts the graph into an undirected graph.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and will look further into documentation to see if I can find the way to make the graph directed.